# Appending correctly

Tags: python, append

I must define a function that takes in a list of strings. Push, pop and peek.

```
def digit_stack(commands):
    stack = []
    sums = 0
    for i in commands:
        if "PUSH" in i:
            for n in i:
                if n.isdigit():
                    stack.append(int(n))
        return stack
```

However

```
digit_stack("PUSH 3", "PUSH 4") == [3]
```

Why it is just appending the first push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `return` after the first iteration:

```
for i in commands:
    if "PUSH" in i:
        for n in i:
            if n.isdigit():
                stack.append(int(n))
return stack # move outside the loop
```

Comment: OMG, that was embarassing. Thank you

Comment: @Juanvulcano, no worries, easy mistake to make.